# OUI database doesnt include URLs. Does anything else?

Tags: mac

So the title pretty much covers it.  IEEE keeps MAC/OUI records similar to this example:

```
  00-00-00   (hex)          XEROX CORPORATION
  000000     (base 16)      XEROX CORPORATION
                            M/S 105-50C
                            800 PHILLIPS ROAD
                            WEBSTER NY 14580
                            UNITED STATES
```

I'd like to get a home page URL for Xerox and every other organization in the OUI text file.  Is there a companion file that has this info?  Or a script that does a reasonable job of finding a home page given the address fields?  TIA

Comment: Why not simply Google the entity once you've found them?

Comment: I'm looking for websites for all the manufacturers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application to become a publicly registered entity on the OUI/MA-L database run by the IEEE does not contain a field for the website of the requesting company. Some of the companies do not have websites, and others have probably had their sites change multiple times over the years.  You can also request a confidential registration.

In short; You can in theory, for *most* companies, but you're going to have to research the ownership and web presence of each company yourself.

Comment: I understand the answer and its helpful.  It's a relatively short list of companies that hold more than 1 registration.  I'll probably try to maintain that by hand.  Thanks.